# Error when using redirect function inside class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I created a simple app CRUD with `react v18.2.0` to manage users. I managed routing. with `react-router-dom v6.14.0` .

I'm trying to use `redirect()` function inside a class component.

But the following error is displaying:

```
react-dom.development.js:16227 Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    at Object.throwInvalidHookError (react-dom.development.js:16227:1)
    at Object.useContext (react.development.js:1618:1)
    at useNavigate (hooks.tsx:179:1)
    at User.handleClick (bundle.js:133:85)
    at onClick (bundle.js:142:27)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4291:1)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:9041:1)
throwInvalidHookError @ react-dom.development.js:16227
useContext @ react.development.js:1618
useNavigate @ hooks.tsx:179
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:133
onClick @ bundle.js:142
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4291
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:9041
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:9073
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:9086
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:9097
 
...
```

User component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class User extends Component {
  handleClick = (userId) => {
    redirect(`/user/${userId}`);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className="flex flex-row rounded-xl p-4 bg-white ring-1 ring-slate-900/5 hover:bg-slate-200 cursor-pointer"
        onClick={() => this.handleClick(this.props.user.id)}
      >        
        ...
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I see that I can use `window.locate.replace('/pathname')` inside `handleClick` function but I don't know it's a good way.

Comment: Thanks @DrewReese. I would know if it's possible to do a redirect inside a class component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`redirect`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/fetch/redirect) utility can only be called in Data router loader and action functions. `div` elements are non-interactive elements so it would be semantically correct HTML to instead use a link element/component.

Example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class User extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Link
        className="flex flex-row .... cursor-pointer"
        to={`/user/${this.props.user.id}`}
      >
        ...
      </Link>
    );
  }
}
```

If you are needing to issue an imperative navigation action from a callback you'll use the [`useNavigate`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate) hook. Make sure the `div` element has the appropriate accessibility role and attributes (*or just use a `button` element and `onClick` handler*).

Example:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const User = ({ user }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleClick = () => {
    navigate(`/user/${user.id}`);
  }

  return (
    <div
      className="flex flex-row .... cursor-pointer"
      onClick={handleClick}
      onKeypress={handleClick}
      role="button"
      tabIndex={0}
    >
      ...
    </div>
  );
};
```

The above, of course, requires the `User` component to be a React function component in order to use React hooks. If you absolutely must continue to support React class components then follow the [official guidance](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/faq#what-happened-to-withrouter-i-need-it) to create a custom `withRouter` Higher Order Component to access the `useNavigate` hook and inject `navigate` as a React prop.

```
import {
  useLocation,
  useNavigate,
  useParams,
} from "react-router-dom";

const withRouter = Component => props => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const params = useParams();

  return (
    <Component
      {...props}
      router={{ location, navigate, params }}
    />
  );
};
```

```
class User extends Component {
  handleClick = (userId) => {
    this.props.router.navigate(`/user/${userId}`); // <-- (2) access navigate
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className="flex flex-row .... cursor-pointer"
        onClick={() => this.handleClick(this.props.user.id)}
      >        
        ...
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(User); // <-- (1) decorate with HOC
```